# Простое или сложное предложение?

Tags: орфография

Нужна ли тут запятая: "Или тут нет никаких правил(,) и нужно просто запомнить?"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, наречие *тут*- разговорное. А предложение, конечно же, сложное. Обе части односоставные безличные (нет и нужно запомнить). Части сложносочиненного предложения объединены вопросительной интонацией, запятая не нужна.